# How to append an ArrayList of ImageViews into a gridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, adaptor

I am new to android and I'm trying to figure out how to create a gallery of ImageViews on an app.
I have a server running that serves the images to the app which download correctly into a Arraylist of ImageViews.
I just need to add all of these images to a grid view.
I know I need to use an adaptor but I don't know how.

This is the code I have in my activity (images is populated else where)

```
ArrayList<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<>();

GridView table = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.table);
table.setAdapter(new ImageAdaptor(this.getBaseContext(), images));
```

And this is my adaptor

```
public class ImageAdaptor extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ImageView> images;

    public ImageAdaptor(Context context, ArrayList<ImageView> images){
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return this.images.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position){
        return this.images.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ImageView image;
        if (convertView == null){
            image = new ImageView(this.context);
            image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(115, 115));
            image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        }else{
            image = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of making an arraylist of imageview, you should make the arraylist of URLs or drawables (whatever you are trying to load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you should not make the arraylist of views as it wont be efficient for reusing views. However if you still want to do that, then solution is ,

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        return images.get(position);
    }
```